# Cannot not see a UIView subview of a UIView

Tags: swift, uikit

I can not see a UIView subview that I added to my UIView.  I have can clearly see it in the view heirarchy but I just cannot see it when the app is running.

Code:

```
var magnifyingView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.alpha = 1.0
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    return view
}()

guard let cgImage = capturedImage else{return}
    let image = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.right)
    imageView.image = image
    self.addSubview(imageView)
    bottomSection.addSubview(homeButton)
    bottomSection.addSubview(retakeButton)
    bottomSection.addSubview(continueButton)
    self.addSubview(bottomSection)

    showMagifyingView()
    self.bringSubviewToFront(magnifyingView)

private func showMagifyingView(){
    magnifyingView = UIView()
    magnifyingView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 30, y: 30, width: 200, height: 200)
    self.addSubview(magnifyingView)

    magnifyingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    magnifyingView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true
    magnifyingView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true
    magnifyingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    magnifyingView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true

}
```

View Heirarchy (The blue highlighted rectangle UIview is what I cannot see on my app at run time.  Even though it is there and that I have brought it to the front)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `magnifyingView` at the top of your class

```
var magnifyingView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.alpha = 1.0
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    return view
}()
```

but you are adding a different `magnifyingView = UIView()` as subview in your `showMagifyingView()`.